# qtmain error: LNK2038

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I'm writing a Qt project which uses another library which was compiled to be linked statically. After doing tons of research to compile my Qt project using /MT (MSVC2017_64), I found it works by doing:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += /MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MD
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MD
```

Anyways, this fixed the errors my other library was having involving LNK2038, however, when I went to compile, I had one new error of:

```
qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
```

I believe this is due to the fact that qtmain.lib was compiled as a dynamic library? This is perfectly fine for me, but I was wondering how I can specify one library that my project uses to use /MT with. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Compiling Qt statically works, however, for future reference, is there a way to specify one library to be used statically (/MT), and the rest /MD in Qt?

Comment: You mix dynamic and static. Keep the library dynamic too, if your Qt project is dynamic either.

Comment: @user3606329 Thanks for your comment, unfortunately, I really need this library not to be dynamically linked. Also, I'm fine with having my Qt project completely static as well, I didn't see a qtmain.lib file that was statically linked.

Comment: The best advise here would be to compile Qt statically, and link your static library.

Comment: @user3606329 If only it was so easy. You are suggesting that I compile all 41 libraries of Qt statically? That doesn't seem like the easiest option...

Comment: You download the Qt sourcecode and then you run `./configure -static static-runtime && make && make install`. At the end you will get a static Qt, you just need to add the new qmake.exe to your Qt Creator.